# tm struct converts to wrong time_t

Tags: c, timezone, esp32, esp-idf

I have the following code to parse a `datetime string` received from GPS satellites into the `struct tm`, and then use `mktime()` to get the `epoch` from it, the result is correct on my Debian machine, but wrong on my ESP32 with `ESP-IDF`, do you have any suggestion on why this is happening, is something wrong with **DST** or **timezone** stuff?

```
#include "rs_time.h"

time_t time_from_gnss_info_time(const char * datetime_str){
    time_t epoch;
    struct tm tm;
    sscanf(
        datetime_str,
        "%4d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d",
        &tm.tm_year,
        &tm.tm_mon,
        &tm.tm_mday,
        &tm.tm_hour,
        &tm.tm_min,
        &tm.tm_sec
    );
    epoch = mktime(&tm); // result is '1462765068' or Mon May  9 03:37:48 2016
    printf("the date and time is: %s %ld ",ctime(&epoch), time(NULL));
    return epoch;
```

}

the value for `epoch` after using `mktime()` when the `datetime_str` is `'20210913221332'` is: **`1462765068`**, also the `ctime()` representation is : `Mon May  9 03:37:48 2016`

Comment: Your `tm_year` usage is wrong: From man `ctime`:  `int tm_year;   /* Year - 1900 */ `. It should be `2021 - 1900 = 31`

Comment: You don't initialize `tm`

Comment: You must set `tm.tm_isdst` before passing `tm` to `mktime`. If unsure, you can simply set it to `-1` or some other negative value, in order to indicate that it is unknown. You should not leave that object uninitialized, as this could provide false information to `mktime` about whether daylight savings was in effect.

Comment: @Mathieu right, but 2021 - 1900 = 121 :-) Old people like me still remember Y2K, wehn `year % 100` became wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `.tm_year` is years since 1900.  `.tm_mon` is months since January.
- `mktime()` uses all members of `struct tm` (except for `.tm_wday, .tm_yday`) to form the return value.  OP's code did not initialize/set `.tm_isdst` or others - `struct tm` may have more than usual 9 members. Initialize them all.
- `mktime()` forms a `time_t` assuming `struct tm` is a local time, not universal time which is usually what GPS provides.  TZ adjustment may be needed - not yet shown.
- `time_t` does not certainly match a `long`.  Cast to a wide type. (`time_t` may even be floating point.) and match specifiers.
- Add error checking.

```
time_t time_from_gnss_info_time(const char *datetime_str) {
  // Code is likely scanning per the current daylight time setting.
  // Use .tm_isdst = -1 to let mktime to determine it.
  // Or use 0 for standard time or any + value for daylight time.
  // All other members are zeroed
  // struct tm tm; // Not this
  struct tm tm = {.tm_isdst = -1};
  if (sscanf(datetime_str, "%4d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d", &tm.tm_year, &tm.tm_mon,
      &tm.tm_mday, &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &tm.tm_sec) != 6) {
    return -1;
  }
  // Adjust some members.
  tm.tm_year -= 1900;
  tm.tm_mon--;
  time_t epoch = mktime(&tm);
  printf("The date and time is: %s%lld\n", ctime(&epoch),
      (long long) time(NULL));
  return epoch;
}

int main(void) {
  time_t t = time_from_gnss_info_time("20210913221332");
  printf("%lld\n", (long long) t);
}
```

Output

```
The date and time is: Mon Sep 13 22:13:32 2021
1664290016
1631589212
```

Additional error checking possible: extra txt, spaces, signs, extreme values, ...

---

An improve string parsing

```
// if (sscanf(datetime_str, "%4d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d", &tm.tm_year, &tm.tm_mon,
//    &tm.tm_mday, &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &tm.tm_sec) != 6) {

// Look for trailing junk.
char ch;
if (sscanf(datetime_str, "%4d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d%c", &tm.tm_year, &tm.tm_mon,
  &tm.tm_mday, &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &tm.tm_sec, &ch) != 6) {
```

Comment: **thank you** for sharing your knowledge, and especially for `sscanf` error checking and for your tip about casting the value, also I think the struct tm should be initialized with `tm_isdst` instead of `isdst`

Comment: @AhmadMansoori Code corrected.

Comment: @AhmadMansoori Original code printed the current `time_t`.  I'd expect `epoch` was desired.

Comment: yes, you are right, it was my desire too, this part was a mistake.

Comment: Whats the reason for years since 1900? I see it in the man page, but like why

Comment: @lmurdock12 "the reason for years since 1900" is a good question. 1) When `struct tm` was designed it was _very_ common to quote the year in 2 digits, even more so than today as there was no centaury/millennium issue for over 70s years. 2) Design of `struct tm` was not focused on its longevity, but its simplicity. 3) 10 years later MS use 1980 as the epoch year" in file time-stamping. 4) Recall many decisions are based on cost.  Think that then memory cost was a [million times](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/historical-cost-of-computer-memory-and-storage?country=~OWID_WRL) more that today.